# Java MYSQL (with Scenebuilder) - if/else statement only executes else statement when connecting to database

Tags: java, mysql, scenebuilder

I'm using MYSQL in Java along with Scenebuilder to create an ATM program. To start this program, a Scenebuilder GUI shows up and a user needs to type in their account number, press the enter button in the GUI, and either get a Welcome message (the if statement) or a Try Again message (the else statement) on the screen.

My code ONLY gets the else statement aka "Enter correct account details" in the GUI whenever I enter an account number from the database.
I've looked at every answer I can that relates to my problem on here but nothing works. I have tried a boolean and that didn't work for me. I need this program to be able to do both if-else statements to work correctly.

This is my enter button code:

```
public void enterButton(ActionEvent enterBPressed) {
    double inputNumber = 0;

    try {   //GETTING ACCOUNT DETAILS
        // sql to find the account
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        String SQL = "Select accountNo FROM checkingaccount WHERE accountNo ='" + inputNumber + "'";

        this.textResult.clear();
        ResultSet resultCheck = statement.executeQuery(SQL);
        if (resultCheck.next()) {
            String accNo = resultCheck.getString(1);
            textResult.setText("Welcome " + accNo);
        } else {
            textResult.setText("Enter correct account details.");
        }
    } catch (SQLException exx) {
        exx.printStackTrace();
    }

} //end enterButton method
```

This is the database I'm getting data from: [checkingaccount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nn72R.png)

This is also my database connection code just in case I did something wrong and that could be an issue; I know it works since the print statements print out every time:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    //try-catch block to establish connection to database
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.print("Driver loaded\n");

        // Establish a connection
        // Create instance of connection and statement objects
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/javabook", "scott", "tiger");
        System.out.println("Database connected");

        // Create statement
        statement = connection.createStatement();

        //processing resultset - get data from database checkingaccount
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from checkingaccount");
        
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: @user16320675 it's apparently of char type with 6 numbers which I find odd but now it's a dilemma into how to get this to pass into my if/else statement

Comment: I've been trying to retrieve this data as char and convert it to String, these account numbers are coming from the checkingaccount table (provided screenshot in post)